# Which domain should be verified for OAuth consent screen in an Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

I am setting up an OAuth consent screen for my Android app and I am uncertain about which domain needs to be verified with Google. My app's OAuth flow is managed by a backend service that is different from the app's homepage. Users do not interact with a domain directly within the app, but the privacy policy is hosted on the app's homepage.

Should I verify the domain of the app's homepage where the privacy policy is hosted, or the domain of the backend service that handles the OAuth process? Any guidance or documentation that clarifies this would be greatly appreciated.

I have not initiated the verification process yet as I want to ensure I understand which domain to verify correctly. The process takes time and I'd like to avoid any potential missteps that would result in having to restart the process.